# Один сайт - два VPS

Tags: apache, ubuntu

ОС Ubuntu 12.04, apache

**Цель:** чтобы 2 сервера(VPS) обслуживали один сайт. Т.е. чтобы у них была общая база, и если один сервер ляжет, оставался второй который держит сайт. (не обязательно выносить базу на отдельный сервер)

Насколько я понял, есть несколько возможностей это реализовать:

1. Чтобы сервера грузились одинаково(50/50 разделяли нагрузку)
2. Чтобы работал один, и когда он будет падать, работал второй

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону двигаться, и какой из способов выбрать. Либо может я заблуждаюсь, и есть третий способ.

P.S. Надеюсь ничего страшного, что к домену прикручен сертификат ssl, он будет работать на разных серверах?

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во-первых, вам на руткод,
во-вторых -- вам нужен балансировщик нагрузки (например, можно использовать так nginx)

Comment: nginx тут ничем не поможет, потому что он должен стоять на одном из серверов, и если тот упадёт, то некому будет балансировать нагрузку. nginx/haproxy имеет ставить отдельно перед несколькими рабочими серверами.
А для таких конкретно случаев есть dns round robin. Желательно, чтобы хранилище сессионных данных при этом было общим. Насколько я понимаю, у вас нет выделенного сервера БД, поэтому вам предстоит геморрой с репликацией, либо стоит готовиться к ситуации, когда тот сервер, на котором стоит БД упадёт, и второй окажется без БД.

И да, не используйте апаче.

Comment: ну да, но использование отдельного фронтенд-кластера позволило бы проще решить проблему с сессиями. ну а мастер-мастер репликация в марии не так уж сложно делается

Comment: @actionless: ну и как бы оно помогло решить проблему с сессиями, если тот сервер, который держал в памяти сессию пользователя, ушёл в даун?
Репликация, сессии в бд + dns rr, по-моему в данном случае без вариантов.

Comment: ну реплицировать сессии может быть затратным слишком, я имел ввиду, что можно будет направлять одного пользователя на один и тот же бэкенд, но да, сессия потеряется, если один из серверов уйдет в даун.  как заметили в комменте ниже, я немного не так понял вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Сервер-балансировщик нужен, а не сервер нагрузки.

Т.к. нагрузка на неработающем сервере - это бред. :)

А вот сервер балансировщик - самое оно.

Собственно он и следит за состоянием основного сервера и в случае падения его быстро перенаправить все на второй, третий серваки. Их может быть много.

+ нужно все делать в кластере - это не дешево, но это стоит своих денег.

Если ты просто хочешь разбить проект на 2 сервака то балансировка тебе не нужна. Возьми просто облачный сервак и все, не парься. т.к. балансировкой занимаются админы,а не программисты.

Comment: да, про облака очень неплохое замечание, но сбой может быть уровня ос или выполнения, так что облака смогут немного уберечь только от возможности аппаратного сбоя.

фронтенд-кластер балансирующий нагрузку кажется мне самым лучшим вариантом

Comment: Да не нагрузку тебе балансировать нужно! А безотказность системы. Вопрос то не про нагрузку и про балансироваку и безотказность.